# TPM: PCR_Event VS PCR_Extend

Tags: tpm, trusted-computing

The TCG's "Trusted Platform Module Library Specification" states that both commands PCR_Event and PCR_Extend eventually cause an update to the indicated PCR (and its banks). In addition to that we know that a PCR can only be reset or extended.
So what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For TPM2.0 i am aware of 2 differences:

**Affected algorithms**

- PCR_Extend extends only the banks selected by the caller
- PCR_Event extends all banks

**Input size**

- PCR_Extend uses digests, so each value must have the correct size for the corresponding hash algorithm
- PCR_Event can use input data between 0 and 1024 (both inclusive) octets